# Str_replace avoid repeating should replace only once

Tags: php, replace

I am trying to replace the strings but it's working like a loop

```
 $especiais = ["b", "c", "k", "g", "j", "d", "f", "a", "e", "m", "i", "y", "h", "l", "p", "q", "n", "x", "o", "r", "z", "u", "v", "w", "s", "t"];

$certo =  ["pn", "veh", "veh", "ged", "ged", "gal", "or", "un", "graph", "tal", "gon", "gon", "na", "ur", "mals", "ger", "drux", "pal", "med", "don", "ceph", "van", "van", "van", "fam", "gisg"];

$resultado = str_replace($especiais, $certo, $phrase);
```

Example Code returns: **OL** returns **medvanandon**

What I need exactly is **OL** return **MEDUR**

This is what I need each letter replace exact by the correspondent letter, but in this code it's repeating the replace several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a notice on the [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) PHP documentation that states the following;

> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a
> previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also
> the examples in this document.

Instead, I recommend using [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) that allows you to pass a "replacement" array in the format of (from => to), as below example;

```
$replace = [
    'b' => 'pn',
    'c' => 'veh',
    'k' => 'veh',
    'g' => 'ged',
    'j' => 'ged',
    'd' => 'gal',
    'f' => 'or',
    'a' => 'un',
    'e' => 'graph',
    'm' => 'tal',
    'i' => 'gon',
    'y' => 'gon',
    'h' => 'na',
    'l' => 'ur',
    'p' => 'mals',
    'q' => 'ger',
    'n' => 'drux',
    'x' => 'pal',
    'o' => 'med',
    'r' => 'don',
    'z' => 'ceph',
    'u' => 'van',
    'v' => 'van',
    'w' => 'van',
    's' => 'fam',
    't' => 'gisg',
];

$phrase = 'ol';

echo strtr($phrase, $replace);
```

---

This provides your expected output, as below:

```
medur
```

Demo: https://tehplayground.com/5YSxPYZfreiPTz9K

Comment: Could you help me with another solution I forgot to explain I also need this rule to apply only  to silent consoants , *OL SONF* instead of *medur fammeddruxor* be like *our sodruxor*  I mean only  replace consonants which are not followed by a vowel, could you help?